# React js implement styles on Table

Tags: reactjs, datatable, react-native-stylesheet

I'm using react-data-table-component

I have this styles:

```
    const tableCustomStyles = {
        headRow: {
          style: {
            color:'#7A8789',
            backgroundColor: '#E7E7E7',
            font: Fonts.Poppins,
            size: '12px',
            fontWeight: '400',
            borderRadius: '5px',
            marginBottom: '20px'
          },
        },
        rows: {
            style: {
                font: Fonts.Poppins,
                color:'#7A8789',
            },
            stripedStyle: {
              backgroundColor: "red"
            }
        }, 
        cells: {
            style: {
                border: 'none'
            },
        },
    }
```

and I'm ussing on:

```
        <DataTable
          columns={columns}
          data={data}
          selectableRows
          customStyles={tableCustomStyles}
          sortIcon={<ImportExportIcon size={10} />}
          responsive
        />
```

so, I just want, when I checked some item inside of table, it backgroung-color will change on red for example, so I tried using `stripedStyle` option, but is not working, why???

currently I'm getting:

[image]

and I just want get some like:

[image]